# How can I efficiently retrieve details of prior transactions for each customer?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of transactional data, including CustomerID & TransactionDate, and I'm looking to create new columns to tell me the details (date, amount, etc.) of the LAST transaction for each transaction for each customer.

Here's a snapshot of my original table:

| CustomerID | TransactionDate | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 18563 | 2014-12-01 | 560 |
| 18563 | 2019-08-22 | 24 |
| 18563 | 2022-01-24 | 979 |
| 32523 | 2021-11-03 | 1024 |

And here's an idea of what I'm looking for:

| CustomerID | TransactionDate | LastTransDate | Amount | LastTransAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18563 | 2014-12-01 | NULL | 560 | NULL |
| 18563 | 2019-08-22 | 2014-12-01 | 24 | 560 |
| 18563 | 2022-01-24 | 2019-08-22 | 979 | 24 |
| 32523 | 2021-11-03 | NULL | 1024 | NULL |

I have a query using an OUTER APPLY that works, but its way too slow, and I'm not sure how to fix it.
Here's my query:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
       t.CustomerID,
       t.TransactionDate,
       t2.LastTransDate,
       t.Amount,
       t2.Amount LastTransAmount
FROM myTable t
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 
           CustomerID, 
           TransactionDate AS LastTransDate,
           Amount
    FROM myTable
    WHERE t.CustomerID = CustomerID
      AND t.TransactionDate > TransactionDate
    ORDER BY TransactionDate DESC) t2 
GROUP BY t.Customer_ID,
         t.TransactionDate,
         t2.LastTransDate,
         t.Amount,
         t2.Amount,
ORDER BY t.CustomerID, t.TransactionDate
```

This gives me what I want, but it's far too slow. I've tried converting into a LEFT JOIN, but to no avail. I also suspected the GROUP BY is causing the issue, but I don't know how to adjust for that. Any tips would be much appreciated!

Comment: You should try the lag window function

Answer (score 2):

You should use the LAG window function to get the prior values

```
SELECT  
       t.CustomerID,
       t.TransactionDate,
       LAG(t.TransactionDate) OVER(PARTITION BY t.CustomerID ORDER BY t.TransactionDate) LastTransDate,
       t.Amount,
       LAG(t.Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY t.CustomerID ORDER BY t.TransactionDate) LastTransAmount
FROM myTable t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
       t.CustomerID,
       t.TransactionDate,
       lag(t.TransactionDate) OVER(PARTITION BY t.CustomerID ORDER BY t.CustomerID, t.TransactionDate) LastTransDate,
       t.Amount,
       lag(t.Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY t.CustomerID ORDER BY t.CustomerID, t.TransactionDate) LastTransAmount
FROM myTable t
order by t.CustomerID,t.TransactionDate
```

Comment: `LAST_VALUE` will gather exactly the last value, which is the same as the current value, for each row, unless you play with frame specification, or use `LAG`.

Comment: Also you don't need CustomerID inside the `ORDER BY` clause: given you're partitioning on CustomerID, each partition will have always the same value of CustomerID itself. Check [nbk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76386341/12492890)'s answer.